# Call original/mocked function, from within mock

Tags: c++, winapi, hippomocks

I'm trying to mock some `WinAPI` functions via `hippomocks`. How can I call the original/mocked `WinAPI`, from within the mock?

For example, if I mock `CreateFile`, the logic I would like to implement inside the mock which I register via:

```cpp
MockRepository mocks;
mocks.OnCallFunc(::CreateFile).Do(MyCreateFileMock);
```

is to call the original API, and then log its output, before returning the result.

I tried to retrieve `CreateFile` address before calling the mock, and storing it in a global. When I call that global from within the mock I end up calling the mock again.

Comment: Are you confident that you actually got the address of the `CreateFile` function (which isn't the name of a function to begin with), rather than the address of the call stub in the IAT?

Comment: @IInspectable yeah, I've retrieved `CreateFileW` address, from `Kernel32.dll` module via `GetProcAddress`. I see in _WinDbg_ that the returned address -- which is then used inside the mock, to invoke the original API -- indeed corresponds to the symbol `KERNEL32!CreateFileW`.
Maybe I should retrieve `KERNELBASE!CreateFileW` instead? It points to the "actual" API imp after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that retrieving the *WinAPI* address via `kernelbase.dll`, as opposed to retrieving it from `kernel32.dll` gets around *hippomocks* hook -- *kernelbase* is where the actual implementation is.

So retrieving the address by calling `GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("kerelbase.dll"), "<API_NAME>")` allows me to invoke the API from within the mock without a problem.